# Error message: object does not contain attribute when object contains attribute

Tags: python, methods

I'm implementing a "player" module with the foliowing:

- a validation function
- a Player object with username and password attributes
- a change password method for Player

When running the following `change_password` method, I receive an error:

```
while(old_password!=self.password_str):
    AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'password_str'
```

Yet, I am defining `password_str` as attribute of `Player`. Any ideas what's happening?

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, username_str="-", password_str=""):
        while (not validated(password_str)):
            self.password_str=input("Password is invalid. Please try again:")
            self.username=username_str

    def change_password(self,old_password):
        MAX_ATTEMPT=3
        num_of_fails=0
        while(old_password!=self.password_str):
            num_of_fails+=1
            if(num_of_fails<MAX_ATTEMPT):
                old_password=input("Thej passwword entered is invalid. Please try again. \
                (You have "+str(MAX_ATTEMPT-num_of_fails)+" attempts reamining)")
            else:
                print("Incorrect password entered too many times. Your account is temporarily locked.")
                break

        if(num_of_fails<MAX_ATTEMPT):
            new_password=input("please enter a new password.")

            while(not validated(new_password)):
                new_password=input("New password is invalid. Please try again")

            self.password_str=new_password
            print("Password has been successfully changed!")
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your question. Please also add a space before and after `=` and `!=`. Your code is very hard to read with everything crushed together.

Comment: When you initialize your Player, if the password string that is passed to __init__ is valid, then you do not enter the while loop where `self.password_str` gets assigned, so Player does not actually have a `password_str` when you enter `change_password`.

Comment: Could be a problem with the `validated()` function, which you don't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if password is valid then while loop does not get executed and self.password_str does not get initialized. Try below code:

```
 def __init__(self, username_str="-", password_str=""):
    self.password_str = password_str
    while (not validated(self.password_str)):
        self.password_str=input("Password is invalid. Please try again:")
        self.username=`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

If `validated` returns True for the password passed to `__init__`, the content of your while loop won't get executed, so the `password_str` and `username` attributes will not get set at all.